# Protecting Sitecore instance from anonymous access

Tags: configuration, authentication

I used to have [Windows Authentication](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4415/protecting-a-qa-site-from-anonymous-access) in-place and works like a charm!

The thing is, now I have a Sitecore 8.2 update 4 (rev. 170614) and **Forms Authentication** is enabled by default, and whenever I enable Windows Authentication IIS throws a warning

> Challenge-based and login redirect-based authentication cannot be used simultanesously

[image]

So, I wonder how would it be possible to protect my Sitecore 8.2 update 4 from anonymous access and to avoid being indexed by search engines?

Comment: Can you add a `robots.txt` file to disallow everything?

Comment: That's an option but would it be possible to get credentials box like I used to have with Windows Authentication?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here, it might be an option. I implemented a custom login to handle this kind of scenario: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/4415/196

Comment: Thanks for sharing Adam but I am looking for something directly on IIS without any implementation - not sure if possible.